# Unknown pink car fluid running low

Tags: engine, hood, fluid

When I opened the car hood, I see a pink fluid running low, I am not quite sure what the liquid is, and would I be able to add it by myself?

[image]

[image]

What is this pink fluid? And would I be able to add it by myself?

Comment: This is antifreeze aka "coolant". Please say the make, model and year of your vehicle for further advice. Do not add any antifreeze until you learn what type you need, because the wrong type can damage your car. If you have the car's manual, it will say what kind of antifreeze you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the engine coolant reservoir.

Add coolant until it reaches the minimum mark.

**Only** add coolant when the engine and system is cold.
It is dangerous to open the system when it is hot as it is pressurised.

Of course the next question is when was it last checked and have you noticed any evidence of leaks?

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Hmm, I can't see any visible leaking. Any indication that would suggests that there was leaking